# Error from tshark and python

Tags: python, tshark

I am trying to execute this simple tshark command through python but I am not able to succeed and I don't understand the error

OS : Windows 7
Python 3.3

Code is

```
from subprocess import Popen


f = open("C:\\folder2\\test.txt","w")
Popen(["tshark" ,"-r","C:\\folder2\\fvido.pcap","-qz", "io,stat,0"],stdout=f)
```

and the error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pc/Google Drive/Python/tshark1.py", line 6, in <module>
    Popen(["tshark" ,"-r","C:\\folder2\\fvido.pcap","-qz", "io,stat,0"],stdout=f)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 820, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child
    raise WindowsError(*e.args)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: This error appears when the system cannot find the executable. Try entering `tshark` in the command shell to confirm the program is in your PATH.